# The best codimension in Nash's theorem

Tags: riemannian-geometry, smooth-manifolds

I know that Nash's theorem says that every Riemannian manifold (compact or not) is isometrically immersed in a high-dimensional Euclidean space. But I feel a bit confused since I was reading the original article from 1956 and it shows that any $n-$dimensional Riemannian manifold has an isometric embedding into a dimension of $\frac{n(3n+11)}{2}$ or $\frac{n(n+1)(3n+11)}{2}$ depending on if its compact or not. But then I see this result, (found [here](https://www.math.utah.edu/%7Etreiberg/Hilbert/Hilber.pdf)):

[image]

Using this result you would have an isometric immersion of the hyperbolic plane in $\mathbb R^{99}$. But with the other result you would have that $\mathbb H^2$ is isometrically embedded in $\mathbb R^{51}$. I have the following doubts

- In the image you can see that he quotes the 1956 article, but there is no such result in it (at least I have not seen it). In case someone knows where to find this result, I would appreciate it very much since I was looking in books and articles on the subject but I could not find it.
- The theorem of the original article is an improvement in dimension of the theorem of the image? Or is the image theorem not actually a Nash theorem? I feel a bit confused since I have not found a bibliographic reference where I can find it.
- I'm trying to see the smallest codimension that can be found between $n-$dimensional hyperbolic space and a Euclidean space, but as a consequence of a Nash result. I know that there are explicit isometric dives with low codimension, but what I am looking for is to contextualize based on the fact that Nash's theorem provides an isometric immersion but with a very high dimension and then show results with a lower dimension.

But it is not enough for me to know that the dimension is high but I want to know which dimension comes from the "Nash theorem". Any kind of help would help me a lot, thanks.

Comment: You should be able to find more updated results [here](https://bookstore.ams.org/surv-130)

Comment: Gromov’s book Partial Differential Relations also has many results of this kind.